# Examples of 1 dimensional Noetherian rings that aren't domains

Tags: ring-theory, noetherian, krull-dimension

What are some examples of Noetherian Rings of Krull Dimension 1 that are not domains? It is relatively easy to find examples of domains(eg. $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{F}[x]$) however I cannot seem to think of examples that are not domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of two Noetherian rings is Noetherian, and $\dim(A\times B)=\max\{\dim A,\dim B\}$. Therefore, $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ is like you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Two more examples:

- $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z[X]$, where $n$ is composite.
- $K[X,Y]/(XY)$, where $K$ is a field.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if a commutative ring $R$ is Noetherian and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $R/I$ is Noetherian.

$\Bbb Z$ is Noetherian but $\Bbb Z/\langle 6\rangle$ is not a domain as it contains zero-divisors.

Comment: But $\Bbb Z/(6)$  has dimension $0$, not $1$, because it has just two prime ideals, none of which is contained into the other.

Comment: @Gae.S.: Thanks wrong example.